# How can I Publish a jupyter tmpnb server?

Tags: docker, publish, jupyter

I'm trying to publish a tmpnb server, but am stuck. Following the Quickstart at http://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb, I can run the server locally and access it at 172.17.0.1:8000.

However, I can't access the server remotely. I've tried adding *-p 8000:8000* when I create the proxy container with the following command:

docker run -it -p 8000:8000 --net=host -d -e CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN=$TOKEN --name=proxy jupyter/configurable-http-proxy --default-target http://127.0.0.1:9999

I tried to access the server by typing *the machine's IP address:8000* but my browser still returns "This site can't be reached."

The logs for proxy are:

docker logs --details 45d836f98450
 08:33:20.981 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:9999
 08:33:20.988 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://localhost:8001/api/routes

To verify that I can access other servers run on the same machine I tried the following command: *docker run -d -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook* and was able to accessed it remotely at *the machine's ip address:8888*.

What am I missing?

I'm working on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Docker 17.03.0-ce

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create file named **docker-compose.yml** with content following, then you can launch the container with `docker-compose up`. Since images will be directly pulled errors will be arrested.

```
httpproxy:
  image: jupyter/configurable-http-proxy
  environment:
    CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN: 716238957362948752139417234
  container_name:  tmpnb-proxy
  net: "host"
  command: --default-target http://127.0.0.1:9999
  ports:
    - 8000:8000

tmpnb_orchestrate:
  image: jupyter/tmpnb
  net: "host"
  container_name: tmpnb_orchestrate
  environment:
    CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN: $TOKEN$
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock
  command: python orchestrate.py --command='jupyter notebook --no-browser --port {port} --ip=0.0.0.0 --NotebookApp.base_url=/{base_path} --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --NotebookApp.token="" --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still running into trouble though: the server can't be found from another computer over http. I'm not getting any error messages, but it seems port 8000 is still not accepting requests. Here's the logs for tmpnb-proxy:  21:55:30.237 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:9999
 21:55:30.253 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://localhost:8001/api/routes

Comment: You need to check if you've connected port 8000 to available port on host running docker image. Am not 100% confident about how to get it done via docker compose

Comment: How can I check that? Since it's not working, I assume that port 8000 isn't working, but don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is available from the github.com/jupyter/tmpnb README.md file. At the end of the file under the heading "Development" three commands are listed:

git clone https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb.git

cd tmpnb

make dev

These commands clone the tmpnb repository, cd into the tmpnb repository, and run the "dev" command from the the makefile contained in the tmpnb repository. On my machine, entering those commands created a notebook on a temporary server that I could access remotely. Beware that the "make dev" command deletes potentially conflicting docker containers as part of the launching process.

Some insight into how this works can be gained by looking inside the makefile. When the configurable-http-proxy image is run on Docker, both port 8000 and 8001 are published, and the tmpnb image is run with CONFIGPROXY_ENDPOINT=http://proxy:8001